# Process PHP files from a network share in a vmware virtual machine

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, virtualization, permissions

As a testing environment, I have set up a vmware virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2. I have Apache and PHP installed (as part of the xampp package). I am doing the development outside of the VM, and so want Apache to serve PHP files from a VM shared folder (which appears as a network share in the VM). I have done this by creating an NTFS symbolic link in Apache's `htdocs` directory. I can access this directory from the browser, and plain-text files are readable. However, PHP fails to process files, instead returning the following error:

> **Warning:** Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **Unknown** on line **0**
>
> **Fatal error:** Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampplite/htdocs/path/to/file.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampplite\php\PEAR') in **Unknown** on line **0**

It appears to be a permissions issue — PHP doesn't seem to be allowed to read the file to process it. However, Apache has no problem opening files in the directory. I cannot figure out how to give PHP the necessary permissions to process the file. Does anybody know of a way to make this work, or else another solution for getting the files into the VM automatically while I develop on the host machine?

Comment: PHP uses the same permissions Apache does.  A 'no such file or directory' error usually indicates you have an incorrect path, not bad permissions.

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini. You may need to update your include_path variable or to include this directory into the safe_mode_include/exec_dir variables.